# mysql stored procedure looping through days

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am not sure, if it is a bug. On this procedure, my Output gets NULL after some time:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `rebuild_cache_days`()
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE SID INT;
    DECLARE M INT;
    DECLARE Y INT;
    DECLARE D INT;

    DECLARE sDone INT;
    DECLARE tDone INT;

    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT `SensorID` FROM `temp_sensors`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET sDone = 1;

    OPEN curs;
    SET sDone = 0;

    loopSID: REPEAT
        FETCH curs INTO SID;
        SELECT DAY(`Timestamp`), MONTH(`Timestamp`), YEAR(`Timestamp`) FROM `temp_log` WHERE `SensorID` = SID ORDER BY `Timestamp` ASC LIMIT 1 INTO D, M, Y;
        SET tDone = 0;
        loopTime: REPEAT
            SELECT CONCAT('process SensorID ', SID, ' date ', Y, '-', M, '-', D) AS Output;
            DELETE FROM `temp_cache_days` WHERE `SensorID` = SID AND `Timestamp` = CONCAT(Y, '-', M,'-', D,' 00:00:00');
            INSERT INTO `temp_cache_days` (`SensorID`, `Timestamp`, `Avg`, `Min`, `Max`)
            SELECT `SensorID`, CONCAT(Y, '-', M,'-', D,' 00:00:00') AS TS,
                    ROUND(AVG(`Temperatur`), 1) AS Avg, ROUND(MIN(`Temperatur`), 1) AS Min, ROUND(MAX(`Temperatur`), 1) AS Max
            FROM `temp_log` WHERE `SensorID` = SID
            AND `Timestamp` BETWEEN CONCAT(Y, '-', M,'-', D,' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(Y, '-', M,'-', D,' 23:59:59')
            GROUP BY TS LIMIT 1;
            SELECT  DAY(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(Y, '-', M,'-', D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
                    MONTH(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(Y, '-', M,'-', D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
                    YEAR(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(Y, '-', M,'-', D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) INTO D, M, Y;
            IF CONCAT(Y,'-',M,'-01 00:00:00') >= CONCAT(CURDATE(), " ",CURTIME()) THEN
                SET tDone = 1;
            END IF;
        UNTIL tDone END REPEAT loopTime;
    UNTIL sDone END REPEAT loopSID;
    SELECT CONCAT('process done') AS Output;
    CLOSE curs;
END
```

And thats the Output:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Output                            |
+-----------------------------------+
| process SensorID 1 date 2013-6-29 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,30 sec)

+-----------------------------------+
| Output                            |
+-----------------------------------+
| process SensorID 1 date 2013-7-30 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,45 sec)

+-----------------------------------+
| Output                            |
+-----------------------------------+
| process SensorID 1 date 2013-8-31 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,78 sec)

+----------------------------------+
| Output                           |
+----------------------------------+
| process SensorID 1 date 2013-8-1 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,93 sec)

+----------------------------------+
| Output                           |
+----------------------------------+
| process SensorID 1 date 2013-8-2 |
+----------------------------------+

[...cut...]

+-----------------------------------+
| Output                            |
+-----------------------------------+
| process SensorID 1 date 2013-8-27 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (5,36 sec)

+-----------------------------------+
| Output                            |
+-----------------------------------+
| process SensorID 1 date 2013-8-28 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (5,55 sec)

+-----------------------------------+
| Output                            |
+-----------------------------------+
| process SensorID 1 date 2013-8-29 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (5,71 sec)

+-----------------------------------+
| Output                            |
+-----------------------------------+
| process SensorID 1 date 2013-8-30 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (5,87 sec)

+--------+
| Output |
+--------+
| NULL   |
+--------+
1 row in set (6,03 sec)

+--------+
| Output |
+--------+
| NULL   |
+--------+
1 row in set (6,03 sec)
```

So, at least it outputs only NULL every time and before the date is jumping.
I revisited the code more times, but could not find any failure.

It seams, that the DATE_ADD has a problem, because also when I remove the lines with DELETE and INSERT INTO ... SELECT I only get NULL as output.

```
# dpkg -l | grep mysql
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                          4.028-2                                    i386         Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysqlclient18:i386                      5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.04.1                    i386         MySQL database client library
ii  mysql-client-5.6                           5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.04.1                    i386         MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-5.6                      5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.04.1                    i386         MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common                               5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.04.1                    all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  mysql-server                               5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.04.1                    all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-server-5.6                           5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.04.1                    i386         MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-5.6                      5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.04.1                    i386         MySQL database server binaries
rc  php5-mysql                                 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6                        i386         MySQL module for php5
ii  php5-mysqlnd                               5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.4                      i386         MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
```

EDIT:

I also tryd the manual way, which results in the same problem:

```
mysql> Set @D = 27, @M = 6, @Y = 2013;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DAY(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(@Y, '-', @M, '-', @D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS D,
    -> MONTH(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(@Y, '-', @M, '-', @D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS M,
    -> YEAR(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(@Y, '-', @M, '-', @D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS Y INTO @D, @M, @Y;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @D, @M, @Y;
+------+------+------+
| @D   | @M   | @Y   |
+------+------+------+
|   28 |    6 | 2013 |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DAY(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(@Y, '-', @M, '-', @D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS D, MONTH(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(@Y, '-', @M, '-', @D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS M, YEAR(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(@Y, '-', @M, '-', @D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS Y INTO @D, @M, @Y;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @D, @M, @Y;                                                                                                                                                                            +------+------+------+
| @D   | @M   | @Y   |
+------+------+------+
|   29 |    6 | 2013 |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DAY(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(@Y, '-', @M, '-', @D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS D, MONTH(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(@Y, '-', @M, '-', @D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS M, YEAR(DATE_ADD(CONCAT(@Y, '-', @M, '-', @D,' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS Y INTO @D, @M, @Y;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @D, @M, @Y;                                                                                                                                                                            +------+------+------+
| @D   | @M   | @Y   |
+------+------+------+
|   30 |    7 | 2013 |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I dont know what is wrong with keeping Day, Month and Year in seperate vars, but my solution is (and yeah, its the more elegant way), to use only one var which holds the complete Daytime.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE SID INT;
    DECLARE Dt DATETIME ;

    DECLARE sDone INT;
    DECLARE tDone INT;

    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT `SensorID` FROM `temp_sensors`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET sDone = 1;

    OPEN curs;
    SET sDone = 0;

    loopSID: REPEAT
        FETCH curs INTO SID;
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') FROM `temp_log` WHERE `SensorID` = SID ORDER BY `Timestamp` ASC LIMIT 1 INTO Dt;
        SET tDone = 0;
        loopTime: REPEAT
            SELECT CONCAT('process SensorID ', SID, ' date ', Dt) AS Output;
            DELETE FROM `temp_cache_days` WHERE `SensorID` = SID AND `Timestamp` = Dt;
            INSERT INTO `temp_cache_days` (`SensorID`, `Timestamp`, `Avg`, `Min`, `Max`)
            SELECT `SensorID`, Dt AS TS,
                    ROUND(AVG(`Temperatur`), 1) AS Avg, ROUND(MIN(`Temperatur`), 1) AS Min, ROUND(MAX(`Temperatur`), 1) AS Max
            FROM `temp_log` WHERE `SensorID` = SID
            AND `Timestamp` BETWEEN Dt AND DATE_FORMAT(Dt, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
            GROUP BY TS LIMIT 1;
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') INTO Dt;
            IF Dt >= CONCAT(CURDATE(), " ",CURTIME()) THEN
                SET tDone = 1;
            END IF;
        UNTIL tDone END REPEAT loopTime;
    UNTIL sDone END REPEAT loopSID;
    SELECT CONCAT('process done') AS Output;
    CLOSE curs;
END
```